# PDF encoding with python requests library broken

Tags: python, json, pdf, python-requests

I'm using Python to request and iterate over a JSON response, then send another request using the Requests library to download a file, based on a parameter from the JSON, like so:

```
url = attachmentIndex['url'] # location of the file
response = requests.get(url, stream=True, auth=('xxxxx', 'xxxxx'))
with open(attachmentIndex['name'], 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
del response
```

The issue I'm facing is PDFs are being encoded strangely, if I try to open one, it suggests the file was damaged. Below is a screenshot of the top content if I open a saved PDF in a text editor:

[image]

Is there anything I can do in python to properly format PDFs?

Comment: Try setting `response.raw.decode_content = True` before copyfileobj